# Laravel Voyager: Translation not working on posts and pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, voyager

I'm trying to add `ar` language to my website but I have a problem the body is not saving it saves `<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>`

I have the request printed how I receive it when updating a post with 2 languages **ar**, **en**.

The request is as this with some dummy text

```
Request {#57 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: array:2 [▶]
  #userResolver: Closure {#1935 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#1994 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#67 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#66 ▼
    #parameters: array:17 [▼
      "_token" => "LjyJ1cgN5tn7yxFbjyHRPAnRzqRKWg8ojRYM7cMP"
      "title_i18n" => "{"en":"Data Services","ar":"خدمة البيانات"}"
      "title" => "Data Services"
      "body_i18n" => "{"ar":""}"
      "body" => """
        <pre style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: SFMono-Regular, Consolas, 'Liberation Mono', Menlo, Courier, monospace; font-size: 11.9px; margin-top: 0px; mar ▶
                 * Set whether or not the multilingual is supported by the BREAD input.\r\n
                 */\r\n
                'bread' =&gt; true,</code></pre>
        """
      "excerpt_i18n" => "{"en":"as ds as d","ar":"as das s dsa"}"
      "excerpt" => "as ds as d"
      "slug_i18n" => "{"en":"data-services1","ar":"khdmh-albyanat"}"
      "slug" => "data-services1"
      "status" => "PUBLISHED"
      "category_id" => "3"
      "meta_description_i18n" => "{"en":"as das dsa d","ar":"asd as dasd a"}"
      "meta_description" => "as das dsa d"
      "meta_keywords_i18n" => "{"en":"as das","ar":"a sdas "}"
      "meta_keywords" => "as das"
      "seo_title_i18n" => "{"en":"Design and conduct surveys and measure relevant indicators in all areas","ar":"Design and conduct surveys and measure relevant indicators in all areas"}"
      "seo_title" => "Design and conduct surveys and measure relevant indicators in all areas"
    ]
  }
  +query: ParameterBag {#65 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#70 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#69 ▶}
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#68 ▶}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#71 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/admin/posts"
  #requestUri: "/admin/posts"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#2051 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

My voyager.php for multilanguage config is like this

```
'multilingual' => [
    /*
     * Set whether or not the multilingual is supported by the BREAD input.
     */
    'bread' => true,
    /*
     * Set whether or not the multilingual is supported by the BREAD input.
     */
    'enabled' => true,

    /*
     * Set whether or not the admin layout default is RTL.
     */
    'rtl' => false,

    /*
     * Select default language
     */
    'default' => 'en',

    /*
     * Select languages that are supported.
     */
    'locales' => [
        'en',
        'ar',
    ],
],
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1):

I searched a lot, finally I tried to solve it by turning around. The solution or let's say the problem here is in this file:

> posts/add-edit.blade.php

and if you remove it the bread will work perfectly with default template for posts add-edit. I think this will help a little but I don't know why this issue appear.